# Half-Syllables in English?

Tags: syllables

Has any authority recognized what we could call "half-syllables"? I.e., "Air" being pronounced /ay-r or /eh-r; not quite two whole syllables, but more than one. Or "I" pronounced /ah-e {except in the U.S. South, where it's just /ah.}

Comment: They're (and *there* and *their*) [**diphthongs**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphthong) *- two adjacent vowel sounds occurring **within the same syllable***.

Comment: Not that I know of.  It would be like a musical rhythm of 5/4 where each measure has a dotted half note followed by a half note.  Try humming that!

Comment: FF has provided a good link. Note that many common dipthongs are *heard* as single phonemes; "no highway cowboys" has 5 dipthongs in it, but only 5 syllables.

Comment: @GregLee https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintuple_meter If you can dance to it, you can hum it.

Comment: @MετάEd, I didn't just say 5/4 time, but two beats to the measure, with the first beat 1 1/2 times as long as the second.  I don't see any such rhythm mentioned in the Wikipedia article on quintuple meter.

Answer (score 4):

In a way...'sesquisyllabic' describes one-and-a-half syllable words, and they are recognized at least theoretically, by some authorities, in English. See, for example, ["SESQUISYLLABLES OF ENGLISH: THE STRUCTURE OF VOWEL-LIQUID SYLLABLES"](http://conf.ling.cornell.edu/pdfs/Lavoie_Cohn_1999.pdf), by Lisa M. Lavoie and Abigail C. Cohn, Cornell Univ.

By their account, the juxtaposition of a liquid consonant and a dipthong can produce a 'half-syllable' pronunciation. The account applies to 'air', but not 'I'.

Comment: This is the first I've heard of sesquisyllables. Thank you! I was never fully satisfied with the "one syllable, just one, only one" explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The word *air* has been classified as varisyllabic, meaning it can have either one or two syllables. See [this blog entry](http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2009/12/triphthongs-anyone.html) written by renowned phonetician John Wells. This classification also extends to the vowels in *near* and *cure*.

I'd personally classify the vowels of *real*, *fool*, *vile*, *howl*, *foil*, and *pale* as varisyllabic also, but that classification seems to be less common.

I don't think i've seen anything classifying *I* as varisyllabic—it is generally classified as a one-syllable diphthong in English. Quite possibly speakers of some foreign languages hear it as two syllables, but native English speakers generally don't.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, they're diphthongs, according to the standard definition of a diphthong found here:

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/diphthong