# number of syllables in GIRL

Tags: american-english, phonology, syllables

I (US Mid-West) definitely pronounce this as having two syllables, with a schwa between  the R and the L.  In fact, I find it difficult to make a consonant cluster of RL.  This is contradicted but dictionary entries that give the pronunciation as having one syllable.

How many syllables does the word have?

Comment: This is just the result of variable syllabification of /l/. Also discussed in the answers to [Half-Syllables in English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/283588) in reference to words with diphthongs like *tile.* The rhotic vowels (or vowel + coda /r/ sequences, however you analyze them) of American English are similar in some ways to diphthongs. Also related: [How many syllables are in the word 'hour'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80224)

Comment: Is the only difference in how you pronounce _pearl_ and _peril_ the first vowel sound? If so, you're really pronouncing _girl_ with two syllables. Otherwise, you're just hearing an incidental sound as you go from an American r to an equally American dark l.

Comment: @KarlG: "pearl" and "peril" have different vowel sounds. You'd need to use an example like "referral" or "demurral" to get the right vowel sound (although they don't start with the same sounds as *girl* or *pearl*). Maybe compare the second part of *referral* and the word *furl.*

Comment: They don't have to rhyme to tell if there's a real vowel there. The point is the schwa in the second syllable of _peril_. But _referral girl_ would work fine. Or maybe _referral_ _unfurl_.

Comment: peril, referral, unfurl, girl, pearl are all perfect rhymes  for me.

Comment: @Kim Did you grow up in the Northern Mid-West (Michigan, Minnesota) or southern (Missouri, Southern Illinois/Indiana) (or somewhere in between)? Rural or  suburban or urban?

Answer (score 6):

For many American English speakers, the distinction between /l/ and /əl/ is unclear when /l/ is in the coda of a syllable (it doesn't necessarily have to constitute the entire coda: see the [related question about words like *child, wild,* and *field*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103007/syllable-count-for-apparent-monosyllabic-words)) after a tense vowel, a diphthong, or a rhotic vowel. The exact set of vowels associated with this merger may vary between speakers; for example, I feel like I have a fairly robust distinction between /el/ (as in *trail*) and /eəl/ (as in *betrayal*) and /ol/ (as in *stole*) and /oəl/ (as in *bestowal*) although in fast speech I can imagine that I might merge them. (Normally, I pronounce /el/ as something like [eə̯ɫ] and [eəl] as something like [eɪ̯əɫ]). But I don't have a strong distinction between /oɪl/ and /oɪəl/: for me, it feels like *oil* basically rhymes with *loyal.*

This means that words that show this variation have an unclear number of syllables.

Wikipedia covers the possible environments in a section titled "[Vile–vial merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/l/#Vile%E2%80%93vial_merger)" of the article "English-language vowel changes before historic /l/":

> In some rhotic accents, [a merger may occur between] /-ˈɜːrl/ (girl, hurl, pearl, etc.) and /-ˈɜːrəl/ (referral), usually skewing towards two syllables.

Comment: Arlberg seems to have no pronunciation problems.

Answer (score 1):

In the standard General American accent, 'girl' has a single syllable, /gɚl/ or /gərl/.

But a large number of people separate 'rl'. This is similar to how the 'l' in bottle forms a syllable all by itself. This is called a [syllabic l'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllabic_consonant). The sounds (which is not the same as letters) of 'r', 'm' and 'n' also can do that, be a syllable without the usual expected vowel as center of the [syllable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllable), though often the  schwa 'ə' or 'uh' is considered the syllabic nucleus that comes with a syllabic consonant.

This is not an uncommon variant in all American varieties of English. It is not characteristic of any particular dialect. Some people in all varieties do it. That means that saying it does not pinpoint you to a particular accent, it is an acceptable variation in all accents.

It is not surprising that the [consonant cluster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonant_cluster) 'rl' is sometimes separated. It is often a very difficult pair to pronounce [by children](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7TTb9qi230A) and [non-native speakers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SskKMbX6qmk). Notice in the second clip, the announcer, who has a British English accent, gives two syllables for 'squirrel' which is perfectly natural alternative.

This is in contrast to the other direction. Some words, like 'fire' or ['desire'](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+many+syllables+are+there+in+desire&oq=how+many+syllables+in+desire), which in the standard pronunciation have two syllables for 'ire' = /aɪ ɚ/ or /aɪ ər/, can reduce to /ar/. It's not like the syllable distinction was emphasized in the standard pronunciation, but especially in [the South](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_American_English) or in the very similar [AAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_English), they are sometimes [non-rhotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhoticity_in_English) (drop word final 'r's) and [monophthongization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monophthongization#English) (saying 'Ah' for 'I').

Comment: To me, “this girl” and “the squirrel” seem closer to each other than either does to “referral”.

Comment: @tchrist Same here. Also for me is that however many syllables some one says, it doesn't stand out as 'different', unlike, say dropping r's. There's a tiny bit of similar phenomenon called the ['vile-vial' merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_vowel_changes_before_historic_/l/#Vile%E2%80%93vial_merger) (I can't tell the difference between those two so I suppose I got it). But 'Nile' and 'denial' are not exact rhymes for me.